# Outputting table column to front end

Tags: php

i just want to ask 1 thing..

Is it ok to output our table column to client?

Table UserList with 3 column id, username_user, password_pass

and we output to client with same table name..

output

```
[0] => [
    "id" => a
    "username_user" => b
    "password_pass" => c

]
```

Comment: It is never alright to show a password. ___NOTE___ For security, the password should be hashed, and if it was it would be of no use the the user anyway.

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry, i don't mean to show the password without hashing, i just giving example with the return array format, not the value.